# Отправка AJAX запроса из скрипта в Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

В Laravel имеется роут с помощью которого запрашиваются данные из БД по id

```
Route::get('/organisation/{id}', 'OrganisationController@edit');
```

Имеется скрипт, который должен формировать этот URL

```
function (obj) {                                    
    target = $node.id.match(/[a-z]+|[^a-z]+/gi);
    model = target[0].toLowerCase(); //Получаем organisation
    id = target[1];  //Получаем например id=5
    $.get( model, {id : id});
});
```

Мне нужно получить запрос вида http://test/organisation/5. А отправляется http://test/organisation?id=5. Соответственно он не подходит под роут.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто добавьте `+'/'+id` к 1-му параметру и уберите 2-й:

```
$.get( model+'/'+id);
```

2-й параметр задает строку запроса URL - все что идет после `?`, т.е. то от чего вы хотите избавиться.